# Syncing IMAP server & local copy of messages

Tags: imap, synchronization, local, directory

Im new to working with IMAP from a programmers perspective, but trying to write a simple IMAP email client.

I have a 3rd party control that does most of the heavy lifting connecting 7 talkking to the server. what I need is more info on how to create and sync an "offline version" (local copy).

I also probably want to do all of the organizing of messages, folders etc locally and eventually "sync" with the server. There must be a standard way of dealing with this in IMAP.

Thanks

Comment: There really isn't.  You're basically writing an entire email client at this point.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not reinvent the wheel, the best solution is use the sysadmin way. Check **[offlineimap](http://www.offlineimap.org/)** this is an script with a small [configuration file](http://www.offlineimap.org/doc/conf_examples.html) that can sync your imap mail server with ssl support. local to remote or remote to local.

```
$dnf install offlineimap
$vi ~/.offlineimaprc
$offlineimap
```